# why i am getting this error on using Link tag from next/link? Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

*hey guys, I know this question is already been asked but I did not get an appropriate answer. I got this error on using next/link . whenever I replace the anchor tag with the "Link" tag I got this error.I will be very thankful if somebody can help*

**code**

```
import {APP_NAME} from '../config';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Navbar=()=>{
    return(
        <>
    <nav className='navbar bg-success'>
        <h1>
            <Link href="/dashboard" ><i className="fas fa-code"></i><a>{App_name}</a></Link>
        </h1>
        <ul>
            <li><Link href="#"><a>Jobseeker</a></Link>
               </li>
            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Employer</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3><a href=""><i className =""></i>Account</a>
        
        </h3>
    </nav>
         <div className="bottom-nav ">
        
        <div className="bottom-item">
            <i className="fas fa-columns text-primary "></i>
            <p className=" text-primary">Dashboard</p>
        
        </div>
        <div className="bottom-item">
            <i className="fas fa-user text-primary "></i>
            <p className=" text-primary">jobseeker</p>
        
        </div>
        <div className="bottom-item">
            <i className="fas fa-users text-primary "></i>
            <p className=" text-primary">community</p>
        
        </div>
        <div className="bottom-item">
            <i className="fas fa-user text-primary "></i>
            <p className=" text-primary">Profile</p>
        
        </div>
        
    </div>
    </>
    )
}
export default Navbar;
```

Comment: You have `<Link href="/dashboard" ><i ...></i><a>{...}</a></Link>`. This link has *two* adjacent children. The link expects a *single* child, as per the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
<Link href="/dashboard" ><a><i className="fas fa-code"/><span>{App_name}</span></a></Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like the error stated, `<Link>` was only expecting a single chid, while you have `<li>` and `<a>`. Wrap the `<a>` under `<li>`, you should be able to fix the problem.